# How to write a linqu query with this foreach loop

Tags: c#, linq, xamarin, xamarin.forms

This  below is my code and I want to write a linq query for this three list (Dictionaryfilter,collectionfilter,reffrencefilter) this as are mmy list and want to add when item is selected then add into a SelectedIdList ,Using Linq in c#

```
SelectedIdList = new List<long>();
foreach (var item in DictionariesFilter)
{
    if (item.IsSelected)
    {
        SelectedIdList.Add(item.DictionaryId);
    }
}

foreach (var item in CollectionsFilter)
{
    if (item.IsSelected)
    {
        SelectedIdList.Add(item.DictionaryId);
    }
}

foreach (var item in RefrencesFilter)
{
    if (item.IsSelected)
    {
        SelectedIdList.Add(item.DictionaryId);
    }                                                          
}
```

Comment: Do a `Where` and then `Select`.

Comment: make Sure my list is 

SelectedIdList = new List<long>();

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils : And `SelectMany` and `ToList`.

Comment: Note that the two answers you've received didn't work because you haven't provided enough information. It sounds like you've got a mixture of `int` and `long` values. This is where a [mcve] is so important - if you'd provided all the context to start with, I suspect that by now you'd have received working answers.

Comment: Sorry Jon ,I am new in this platform ,and thanks for giving me advise .I Accept it .And improve my skill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could look something like:

```
SelectedIdList.AddRange(
    DictionariesFilter.Where(x=>x.IsSelected).Select(x=>(long)x.DictionaryId)
);
SelectedIdList.AddRange(
    CollectionsFilter.Where(x=>x.IsSelected).Select(x=>(long)x.DictionaryId)
);
SelectedIdList.AddRange(
    RefrencesFilter.Where(x=>x.IsSelected).Select(x=>(long)x.DictionaryId)
);
```

Comment: My SelestedIdList Is long  ,my all list is observable collection list but ony selectedId List Is in long Is there any suggestion 
 SelectedIdList = new List<long>();

                   SelectedIdList.AddRange(
                 DictionariesFilter.Where(x => x.IsSelected).Select(x => x.DictionaryId));

                SelectedIdList.AddRange(
                    CollectionsFilter.Where(x => x.IsSelected).Select(x => x.DictionaryId));

                SelectedIdList.AddRange(
                    RefrencesFilter.Where(x => x.IsSelected).Select(x => x.DictionaryId));

Comment: If the code you posted works, my code should work too. Are you getting an error message? Paste the exact error if you are

Comment: Cannot Convert "Sysyten.collection.generic.IEnumrable<int>" to "Sysyten.collection.generic.IEnumrable<long>"

Comment: Cast all the DictionaryIds to long (edited answer to show it)

Comment: Yes Now It's Working ,Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is to simply use [Where](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-5.0) and [Concat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.concat?view=net-5.0).

```
SelectedIdList = DictionariesFilter.Where(x => x.IsSelected).Select(x => (long)x.DictionaryId)
    .Concat(CollectionsFilter.Where(x => x.IsSelected).Select(x => (long)x.DictionaryId))
    .Concat(RefrencesFilter.Where(x => x.IsSelected).Select(x => (long)x.DictionaryId))
    .ToList();
```

If they have a common interface it could be simplified.

```
public interface IFilter
{
    bool IsSelected { get; }
    long DictionaryId { get; }
}

SelectedIdList = DictionariesFilter
    .Concat(CollectionsFilter)
    .Concat(RefrencesFilter)
    .Where(x => x.IsSelected)
    .Select(x => x.DictionaryId)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: SelectedIdList = DictionariesFilter.Where(x => x.IsSelected).Select(x => (long)x.DictionaryId)
                .Concat(CollectionsFilter.Where(x => x.IsSelected).Select(x => (long)x.DictionaryId))
                .Concat(RefrencesFilter.Where(x => x.IsSelected).Select(x => (long)x.DictionaryId))
                .ToList();
                


You forgot add long ,Thank you now its working

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

```
var results1 = from item in DictionariesFilter
                              where item.IsSelected
                              select item.DictionaryId;
     selectedList.Add(results1);
```

and in similar way you could do for the rest of loops.

Comment: The results1 variable has a error cannot convert system.collection 

var results1 = from item in DictionariesFilter
                               where item.IsSelected
                               select item.DictionaryId;
                SelectedIdList.Add(results1);

Comment: you need to cast DictionaryId to long as (long)item.DictionaryId or make sure DictionaryId is of long type.

Answer (score 0):

You could try, if possible:

```
public interface IFilter
{
    bool IsSelected { get; }
    int DictionaryId { get; }
}

SelectedIdList = new IFilter[] { DictionariesFilter, CollectionsFilter, ReferencesFilter}
    .SelectMany(dic => dic.Where(x => x.IsSelected).Select(x = > (long)x.DictionaryId) )
    .ToList();
```